# VueJS update data after ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js

I trying to do pagination on my webpage. So it will filter the data accordingly on every page is flipped. How can I update my Vue instance's data after every success ajax call? The correct data is passback on each ajax request is made but the Vue data did not update.

code in `product.php` (as below):

```
<script src="/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="/i.js"></script>

<div class="content">
 <table class="hue">
  <thead>
    //table headings
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr v-for="(value, key) in result">
     <td>{{value.productCode}}</td>
     <td>{{value.productName}}</td>
     //... etc
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

code in `i.js` (as below):

```
function fetchData(p=null){
 var ajaxVue = new Vue({
  el: ".hue > tbody",
  data: {
    result: []
  },
  mounted: function(){
   var self = this;
   $.ajax({
    url:"/a.php",
    method:"GET",
    data:{
     page: p
    },
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(rs){
     console.log(rs.pd[14].code);
     self.result = rs.pd;
     $('#pagination > .pagination').html(rs.pgnt);
     //ajaxVue.$forceUpdate();

    },
    error:function(err){console.log(err);}
   });
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  fetchData();
});
```

Note: the `console.log()` in ajax success function is to show whether the data is changing and correct data is fetch.

example:

```
//there will be 15 data on each request, i just show one for example.
BM23901 //current page: 1
BM19023 //current page: 2
BM39020 //current page: 3
```

but on my `product.php` interface, the shown data remain `BM23901` instead of updating itself after each successful ajax request is made.

I tried `forceUpdate()` from Vue but the instance is still not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use axios instead:

```
try {
    const response = await axios({...});
    console.log(rs.pd[14].code);
    self.result = rs.pd;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I think this code will work perfectly.
But if you still wanna try it with ajax, then I might suggest changing your success function to arrow function:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: (resp) => {
        result = resp.pd;
    },
    ...
});
```

Notice that I dont have to use `self` inside arrow function

Comment: you mean change the whole/part of content in my current fetchData() to above code? I did not use any axios in my past time, not sure axios required other configuration. Do you have any axios documentation that i can refer to? TIA

Comment: It just my recommendation. You dont have to use it if you dont want to.
I think your problem is just about scope so all you need to do is just change the `success` function to array function.

Comment: @boboltm try out this link: https://github.com/axios/axios#example
It's pretty straightforward & easy to use.
All you need to do is :

1. npm install axios

2. const axios = require('axios');

3. Use it just like ajax. But keep in mind 2 things: it dont have success & failure function like ajax but `.then().cacth()` instead. And dont use `then & catch`function. Just use try...catch as I do above

Comment: how can I use axios without npm install (I did not have any nodejs stuff in my pc and in fact my project are not build using nodejs)? I tried include the axios using CDN method, it return 'require' is not defined (by following the example shown in the documentation). And for second recommendation, did not work if not using `self.result` or `this.result` (return blank, unless I point `this` to them) but still the same thing happen as what had I did previously.

Comment: so event you use arrow function but it still not working?
`this.result = rs.pd` still not working inside arrow function?

Comment: after adding `this` then it working fine, but the Vue data still did not update even the ajax request data is pass back

Comment: Can you try `console.log(this.result)` right after ajax call? Like this:

    $.ajax({
         success:function(rs){
         this.result = rs.pd;
         console.log(this.result);
    },
    error:function(err){console.log(err);}
   });

     console.log(this.result);

Comment: the `this.result` array length:0, so i assumed it did not assign/update the vue data.result at all

Comment: the result still remain the same, `this.result` length:0

Comment: Well that's what I'm afraid of, the `this.result` isn't set yet. Dont know why this happen, maybe because of ajax. Try to use axios instead:
`import axios from 'axios';` and see if it work?

Comment: `import axios from 'axios'` return Unexpected identifier when i included that line of code in my `i.js` file. I had include the axios CDN from the documentation in my `product.php` but seem like it cant read. 
Perhaps I should convert all this code into a full Vue framework.

Comment: how about include the cdn link in your Vue file `i.js`?